# MVC controller / PHP request dispatcher

Tags: php, mvc, dynamic-loading

After getting the requested controller from the URI request, it checks whether this exists and whether the requested method (default index) exists within that controller, then calls them.

My intention is to have everything running object oriented so I'm trying to remove any procedural/unattached variables that may appear throughout the code.

My question is, can this code be refined to be more efficient? It works fine, however I've noticed a small increment in time between requesting controllers/methods and I'm not sure where this slow behaviour is coming from.

Note: the intention of this code is to check the URI string (I don't use .htaccess for this) and request a controller and a method from the URI string, for example: site.com/controller/method, site.com/login/recover

**index.php**

```
namespace MVC;
use MVC\libs\URI_Request;

class Index {

    private $controller;
    private $method;

    function __construct() {

        $this->autoload();

        $__REQUEST__ = new URI_Request($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);

        $this->prepareController($__REQUEST__);
        $this->method = $__REQUEST__->getMethod();

        if($this->checkClass()) {
            $this->controller = new $this->controller();

            if($this->checkMethod($__REQUEST__)) {
                $this->controller->{$this->method}();
            }
        }
    }

    function autoload() {
        require_once("Autoloader.php");
        new Autoloader();
    }

    function checkClass() {
        if(class_exists($this->controller)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            echo "controller: error (" . $this->controller . ") does not exist<br>";
        }

        return false;
    }

    function checkMethod($request) {
        if(method_exists($this->controller, $this->method)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            echo "method: (" . $this->method . ") does not exist for requested controller.<br>";
        }
    }

    function prepareController($__REQUEST__) {
        $this->controller = ucfirst($__REQUEST__->getController()) . "Controller";
        $this->controller = '\MVC\controllers\\' . $this->controller;
    }
}

new Index();
```

**routing.php** (prepended file to any request)

```
<?php
    if (preg_match('/\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
        return false;
    } else {
        include 'index.php';
    }
```

**URI_Request.php**

```
<?php

namespace MVC\libs;

class URI_Request {

    private $request;
    private $pairs;
    private $controller;
    private $method;

    function __construct($request) {
        $this->request = trim($request);
        $this->request = explode("/", $this->request);
        $this->request = array_filter($this->request);
        $this->request = $this->handle($request);
    }

    function handle($request) {

        foreach($this->request as $key=>$item) {
            switch($key) {
                case 1:
                    $this->controller = $item;
                break;
                case 2:
                    $this->method = $item;
                break;
                default:
                    if($key > 2) {
                        $item = explode("=", $item);
                        if(isset($item[1])) {
                            //key item pair, data
                            $this->pairs[$item[0]] = $item[1];
                        } else if(isset($item[0])) {
                            echo "<b>WARNING: \"" . $item[0] . "\" has no key/value!</b>";
                        }
                    }
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!$this->controller){
            $this->controller = 'index';
        }

        if(!$this->method) {
            $this->method = 'index';
        }

        if(!$this->pairs) {
            $this->pairs = [];
        }
    }

    function getController() {
        return $this->controller;
    }

    function getMethod() {
        return $this->method;
    }

    function getPairs() {
        return $this->pairs;
    }

    function getRequest() {
        return $this->request;
    }
}
```

**Autoloader.php**

```
<?php

namespace MVC;

class Autoloader {

    function __construct() {
        session_start();
        spl_autoload_register('self::loader');
    }

    static public function loader($className) {
        $filename = str_replace('\\', '/', $className) . '.php';
        $filename = str_replace('MVC/', '', $filename);
        if(file_exists($filename)) {
            require($filename);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't really help with performance, but if you suspect the `URI_Request` handler, here are some ideas:

- get rid of `array_filter` and replace it with `$this->request = rtrim($request, "/");`, which should be faster, and is also easier to understand.
- remove `$this->request = trim($request);`, as it's not needed.

I would probably also rewrite the handle method (it might not necessarily be faster, but I think it's a lot easier to read):

```
function handle($request) {
    if (!isset($this->request[1])) {
        $this->controller = 'index';
        return;
    }

    if (!isset($this->request[2])) {
        $this->method = 'index';
        return;
    }

    $argumentCount = count($this->request);
    for ($i = 3; $i < $argumentCount; $i++) {
        $item = explode("=", $this->request[$i]);
        if(isset($item[1])) {
            $this->pairs[$item[0]] = $item[1];
        } else if(isset($item[0])) {
            echo "<b>WARNING: \"" . htmlspecialchars($item[0], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "\" has no key/value!</b>";
        }
    }
}
```

**Misc**

- magic numbers in `URI_Request`: I would consider `1` and `2` magic numbers in this case, and would pass them to the function as argument. If your application is ever moved into a sub-directory, a user needs to be able to control these variables.
- I wouldn't echo in the `URI_Request` class. If more than one pair of arguments is wrong, you will get a lot of warnings. Also, maybe there will be a point when you want to make a proper 4xx/5xx error page, and then it will be nice to have all those echos in one place already.
- I would get rid of the `autoload` function, because it doesn't really do anything. It's name suggest that it loads something automatically, but it only instantiates the autoloader class.
- `checkClass` and `checkMethod` should probably behave the same, but one returns false and one doesn't.
- also, if the failure message is echoed in the else case, I would move the return false there as well.

Comment: Brilliant - thanks alot, I'll give this a go!

Answer (score 1):

This was originally a comment, but it became too long, so I made it into an answer. I'm not sure this does definately answer your question, nor does it really review your code.

The main issue in your question is:

> "I've noticed a small increment in time between requesting
>   controllers/methods"

but you don't say what you compare it with. Can you tell us?

Also, how big an increment are we talking about? Also specify platform and PHP version. As for your question, apart from a few somewhat awkward OOP choices, I don't see anything that could really slow things down substantially.

My guess is that the delay is somehow in the server. It is given the URL `site.com/login/recover` and somehow you end up loading `site.com/index.php`. You don't tell us how, except that you don't use `.htaccess`, but my guess is that that's the issue.

Comment: I load index.php by appending the routing.php file to any execution (php.ini settings)

The time difference is notable when not pulling the controller/method from the URL but just specifying them in the file as stand alone variables, so perhaps it's something to do with that.

Comment: So what happens when the URL doesn't exist, like with `site.com/login/recover`? I mean exactly. The default would be a http 404 error. That's not what you want.

Comment: I use the class_exists() function to determine whether the controller and the method_exists() function to determine whether that method for that controller exists - and if not, I create a new Controller (parent class of other controllers) and cast the view('404.php');

Comment: I guess what you mean to say is that there a file called `site.com/login/recover/index.php` containing the class `login`, you call this a 'controller', with the method `recover`? That's not really obvious from your question.

Comment: There's no file, there's a LoginController class with a recover() method within it.

Comment: So the request is redirected by the server during a request like `site.com/login/recover`. As I mentioned before, this could cause the delay.

Comment: No it never redirects, just loads the relevant classes for the controller/method.